# Usando mysqli para contar registros

Tags: php, mysqli

Preciso fazer uma contagem de registros.
Eu usava:

```
mysql_num_rows($consulta);
```

Como eu faço a mesma coisa usando mysqli? Pois estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
$tabela_usuarios = "SELECT * FROM owner WHERE owner_email='$email' AND password='$password' ";

$resul = mysqli_query($con, $tabela_usuarios);
$regs = mysqli_num_rows($resul);
```

E a seguinte mensagem aparece na tela:
"Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/petsm976/public_html/php/logon.php on line 15"

Comment: Coloque o trecho anterior a linha de `mysqli_num_rows()`... o erro diz que a sua consulta(retorno de `mysqli_query()`) falhou.

Comment: de acordo com o erro a variavel $consulta esta vazia, use `echo $consulta;` ou `var_dump($consulta);` para ver se existe alguma coisa...

Comment: Tai @rray, o trecho anterior ao mysqli_num_rows, reeditei o post e coloquei.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, a variável não está vazia... Deu um echo nela, rodei o código no SQL do banco e mostra dados.

Comment: `echo $tabela_usuarios` mostra o que ?

Comment: Sinceramente @GustavoSevero eu sugiro que você aprenda PDO porque logo logo o mysqli não "existira", ele sera depreciado...

Comment: @DiegoSouza, mostra isso:
string(88) "SELECT * FROM owner WHERE owner_email='flav.sch@xxx.com.br' AND password='xxx180398' "

Comment: Porque não usa  `SELECT COUNT(owner_email) AS TOTAL FROM owner WHERE owner_email='$email' AND password='$password'`  , ai você da um fetch no resultado e faz validação pegando os dados do campo total.

Comment: @HenriqueDomingosPereira, eu tenho que da um fetch no resultado? Eu não conheço mysqli.

Comment: coloquei como resposta, da uma olhada.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, onde baixo a classe PDO? Ou, como instalo ela?

Comment: @RFL, até o momento não há indícios nenhum de que o mysqli será depreciado. Agora se vc se refere a um a possibilidade futura, na verdade, no futuro qualquer função nativa do PHP pode se tornar depreciada, fica a critério do desenvolvedor.

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma de usar é fazer a contagem direto no SQL, assim:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT COUNT(owner_email) AS TOTAL FROM owner WHERE owner_email='$email' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row['TOTAL']; 
?>
```

E de uma forma mais segura, usando statement:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("host","usuario","senha","banco de dados"); 
$query = "SELECT COUNT(owner_email) AS TOTAL FROM owner WHERE owner_email=? AND password=?";

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query))
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $email, $password);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $total);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);   
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    echo $total;
```

Referencia = http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-stmt.php

Comment: Beleza @HenriqueDomingosPereira, consegui...
Só que depois eu uso isso para pegar os valores da query:

$owner_id = mysqli_use_result($resul, 0, "owner_id");
$userName = mysqli_use_result($resul, 0, "owner_firstName");

E as seguintes mensagens aparecem na tela:

Warning: mysqli_use_result() expects exactly 1 parameter, 3 given in /home/petsm976/public_html/php/logon.php on line 21

Warning: mysqli_use_result() expects exactly 1 parameter, 3 given in /home/petsm976/public_html/php/logon.php on line 22