# contar campos repetidos de uma coluna

Tags: php

Como eu poderia contar os campos repetidos da minha tabela, tentei assim mais não deu certo:

**Segura o nome dos generos**

```
    $generos = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `generos`");

    while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($generos)){

            $nomeGenero             = $res['nome_genero'];
            $nomeGeneroCaracteres   = $res['nome_genero'];

            $gn = [rtrim(''.$nomeGenero.'',',')];

            foreach ($gn as $epAtual){

                @$generoAtual = $urlE[1];

                $contaGeneros = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `seriados`");

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($contaGeneros)){

                    $genero = $row['genero_serie'];

                    $conta = mysqli_num_rows($genero);

                    if($generoAtual == $epAtual){

                        $epAtual = preg_replace('/[-]/ui', ' ',$epAtual);

                            echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ativo">'.utf8_encode($nomeGenero).' <strong>123</strong></a></li>'.PHP_EOL;

                    }else{

                            echo '<li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/genero/'.$nomeGeneroCaracteres.'">'.utf8_encode($nomeGenero).' <strong>123</strong></a></li>'.PHP_EOL;
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Objetivo é deixar assim: `animes 2 | aventura 5 | comedia 7 .....`

**soluçao**

consegui da seguinte forma, esta ai pra quem precisar

```
$generos = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `generos`");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($generos)){

    $nomeGenero             = $res['nome_genero'];
    $nomeGeneroCaracteres   = $res['nome_genero'];

    $generoSerie = $res['nome_genero'];

    $seriadosConta = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT COUNT(genero_serie) AS TOTAL FROM seriados WHERE genero_serie LIKE '%$generoSerie%'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($seriadosConta)){

        $gn = [rtrim(''.$nomeGenero.'',',')];

        foreach ($gn as $epAtual){

        @$generoAtual = $urlE[1];
        if($generoAtual == $epAtual){

        $epAtual = preg_replace('/[-]/ui', ' ',$epAtual);

            echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ativo">'.utf8_encode($nomeGenero).' <strong>'.$row['TOTAL'].'</strong></a></li>'.PHP_EOL;

        }else{
            echo '<li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/genero/'.$nomeGeneroCaracteres.'">'.utf8_encode($nomeGenero).' <strong>'.$row['TOTAL'].'</strong></a></li>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
   }
```

}
}

> Fonte

[usando-mysqli para contar registros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81859/usando-mysqli-para-contar-registros)

Comment: meu deus.. isto vai gastar tanto recurso do servidor `while > foreach > while` ??

Comment: @13dev eu preciso deixa o menu marcado conforme a pagina que a pessao esta, tem outro jeito ?

Comment: reparte o código em funções para que possas reutilizar e tirar vantagem da performance do `PHP`

Comment: @13dev eu sou novato, ja achei um grande passo ter chegado ate aqui

Comment: Não meti nada disso em questão, pois bem dá uma olhadela em `PDO` e `orientação a objectos`, vais adorar! :)

Comment: Se o seu objetivo é apenas contar a quantidade de gêneros, faça direto no sql e não por loops trazendo a sua query completa.

Comment: @LuizPillon seria mais ou menos isso ? `SELECT genero_serie FROM seriados`, mais ai como eu contaria quantos campos tem o mesmo nome direto no sql ? passando o valor dele na url eu consigo contar, o problema e quando nao passo nada url

Comment: vou mandar a query p voce nas respostas

Comment: nao sei pra que votarem negativo se nao ajudam em nada, deixe pra quem quer ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Olá @Mayron, vou colocar um exemplo pra vc ver como pode verificar os valores repetidos:

```
<?php

$valores = array(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4);
$contagem = array_count_values($valores);

foreach($contagem AS $numero => $vezes) {

    /*aqui no if, vc pode definir qual o valor que deseja realizar a contagem dos repetidos*/
    if($vezes == 4) {
        echo "$numero - $vezes<br />";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: nao tem um jeito de conta direto no sql ?

Comment: tenta assim: SELECT   *,
         COUNT(nome_genero) AS qtd_nGenero
FROM  generos
GROUP BY nome_genero
HAVING   COUNT(nome_genero) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(nome_genero) DESC

Comment: while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($generos)){
    $qtd_nGenero = $res['qtd_nGenero'];
   echo $qtd_nGenero;
}

Comment: nao deu certo, ele duplicou somente um campo, fez a contagem certa, mais no segundo duplicado ele tiro uma contagem '5' nem sei da onde vem esse 5

Answer (score 1):

**Segue a query apenas para contagem do seu total de generos.**

```
SELECT distinct(nome_genero), count(nome_genero) FROM generos group by nome_genero;
```